# Mysql: efficient way to join table A and table B, both having multiple columns primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, join

I have two tables; table A and table B
A's schema: (id, col1, col2) - MyISAM
B's schema: (name, col1, col2) - MyISAM

When I try to join these two tables using:

```
select A.* from A left join B on(A.col1 = B.col1 and A.col2 = B.col2)
```

Above query is time consuming.. so I am looking for any better alternatives to it.

Comment: If you have lots of rows in those tables, that's going to take time.

Comment: Please show your table definition queries. This is the best way assuming you have correctly defined the `PRIMARY KEY` and `INDEX` constraints. Also, try to replace `A.*` with `COUNT(*)` to see how much returning the actual data is impacting on the overall performance.

Comment: (col1,col2) is a primary key for both the tables A and B

Comment: In that case, your solution is optimal

Comment: @SayemAhmed table A contains around 50K rows and table B contains around 700K records..

Comment: @SagarG . . . How long is "time consuming"?  With primary keys, your query should be pretty fast.  How many output rows do you expect?

Comment: @Eggplant I have only defined (col1,col2) as a primary key.. no other indexes defined.. could you please let me what indexes definition would optimize the performance of the query?
tableA(id int, col1 int(8), col2 smallint(2))
tableB(name int, col1 int(8), col2 smallint(2))

Comment: @GordonLinoff I only tried to run the query on the subset of the records.. lets say 2K records returned and it took around 10 mins..

Comment: As other people wrote already, having `col1` and `col2` as `PRIMARY KEY` in BOTH tables, this is the best scenario you can have. The *time consuming* reason could be that you are returning a very large dataset. Try to `EXPLAIN` the query to check the execution plan. Also as I wrote before, replace `A.*` with `COUNT(*)` and see the real speed of the query itself, without the dataset returning overhead.

Comment: @Eggplant ok.. I will give it a shot..and analyse further..
Thanks a lot for your prompt reponse guys :)